# TestPage.aspx in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am a beginner in silverlight. I want to know what is TestPage.aspx and TestPage.html in silverlight. Actually i have google it but din't get enough information. Can any one give me answer??

Answer (score 4):

TestPage.aspx and TestPage.html are the pages which will host your Silverlight content. As you might know, Silverlight is just a project (not a web application) and needs a page that can host it.
These pages are created by default and help you to test your XAML content during your development, which you can later remove from your project.

Answer (score 1):

TestPage.html is dynamically generated by the Silverlight application as part of the Debug process. If you take a look at the **Debug** tab for the application properties you will see an option to *Dynamically generate a test page*. If this is selected then you TestPage.html is created in the /Bin/Debug folder of your Silverlight application.

A better solution is to create a web application in the same solution as your Silverlight application then in the properties for the web application go to the **Silverlight Applications** tab and add your existing Silverlight app to the web project. Also make sure that the Silverlight checkbox is ticked in the **Debuggers** section of the Web tab of your web application.